# Caching an offline version of a iPhone web app

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I have an iPhone web app I am trying to write.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

This works fine and I can add it as a web app on my homescreen. I am trying to get it to cache the app so that it can work offline.

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/cache-manifest");
?>
CACHE MANIFEST
index.php
img/arrow.png
img/back_arrow.png
```

(I can't edit the .htaccess so I'm using php to get the write content type)

The page caches fine on mobile safari and I can access it without an internet connection. However, when I add it to the home screen and then disconned the internet (using airplane mode) the app says "[app] could not be opened because it is not connected to the internet."

Where should I look to find out why it works fine in mobile safari but not as a web app?